# C# Timers for game development

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I want to find out the best way of creating time based events in games.
Lets talk for example about Texas Holdem Poker. Server can handle thousands of tables and in every table we have timers: turn timer, hold seat timer and so on.

What is the best way of timers realization for this purpose?

Is System.Timers.Timer class can handle this or it will be more reasonable to create a separate thread with sorted time queue (for example an ascending sorted list with int values which represent time in ms remained)?

Thanks in advance,
Valentin

Comment: You might want to post this question on: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Tim's suggestion is a good one.  I'm interested in seeing their answers.

Comment: @Tim Cooper: I think he is better off here.

Comment: @Tim Cooper: I have posted this question there. The link is http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9050/c-timers-for-game-development

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `System.Timers.Timer` or `System.Threading.Timer`.  Your idea of using a sorted queue is exactly how `System.Threading.Timer` is implemented, so you'd just be wasting your time and adding needless overhead.  `System.Timers.Timer` is a wrapper around `System.Threading.Timer`.

I would not suggest using the current time (i.e. `DateTime.Now` or similar) to provide timeouts, because the clock can change at unpredictable times in unpredictable ways.

If you want to base things on a "current time," then start a `Stopwatch` at the beginning of your program, and use the `Elapsed` property as the "current time" in the game.  So the time that's five seconds from the current time would be:

```
var FiveSecondsFromNow = GameTimer.Elapsed + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
```

The question raised in comments is whether I would suggest using multiple timers with `Elapsed` events, or a list of actions that's maintained in time order and checked periodically (i.e. in a timer or in the main game loop).

My immediate response would be to use a separate timer object for each event that needs to happen.  Doing so takes advantage of multiple cores when they're available (concurrent events can happen concurrently), and prevents me from having to maintain that list of pending actions.  I know that the timer queue implementation can handle thousands of individual timers without trouble, and it's almost certain that their implementation of the timer queue is going to be more efficient than mine.

Using timers simplifies the code, unless you have multithreading issues.  And I'm all for simple.  I'd only go to a manually maintained list of pending actions if I ran into performance problems with the timers.  And I'd be *very sure* that the timers were the culprit before I went to the effort of eliminating them.

Comment: Thanks for the information on the implementation of Timers! Question remains, how would you use `Timer`. One global timer and checking passed time, or a timer for every 'event' which needs to happen, and using the Elapsed event.

Answer (score 1):

I often find not using timers at all the best approach. Just store timestamps, and when you do processing, check the difference of the current time with the stored timestamp.

Minimize using threads when other easy solutions are available.

You should be able to 'process' all your tables often enough to handle all logic. Unless we are talking really big numbers this shouldn't be a problem.

Unless you have some very heavy logic in your game which takes up a lot of processing, most likely not in texas hold'em, you shouldn't use threads, they only complicate things. Why would you want to run something 'simultaneous' when it is perfectly possible to update the entire state of the games in one short update?

Comment: Yes, it is the best solution you offered, but sometimes it is not suitable. For example in Texas Holdem Poker I have a turn timer, so if I will just store timestamp during turn move when should I start processing it and how to know when needed time is reached? Of course I can have separate thread running that will run though all the tables and compare timestamps for example every second, but it the worst way I think

Comment: @Valentin: No it isn't, it is what is called a 'game loop'. [This](http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/) is an excellent article on the topic.

Comment: @Steven Jeuris: Of course, the game loop is the heartbeat in every "client" game, but this rule not always can be applied to the game server IMHO

Comment: @Valentin: Perhaps for security/stability reasons you could consider running every table on a different process. Or to automatically use multi-core CPUs. But as I specified in my update, don't complicate things when it's possible without. Try writing a simple 'server' which simply iterates over 'thousands' of tables and does e.g. some timestamp checks. I don't see this taking longer than 1 second. Threading isn't a magic 'fix' to make slow things run faster.

Comment: The problem with using "current time" is that the time can change underneath you in unexpected (and unpredictable) ways. Daylight saving time is the big culprit, but also the user can change the clock manually. And "don't do that" is not a particularly good response because users typically don't expect (and in my opinion, shouldn't expect) that changing the clock would cause the game to crash or exhibit strange behavior.

Comment: @Jim Mischel: I never really bothered about that. What is considered a safer approach? Starting a timer and using this as reference time?

Comment: @Steven Jeuris: A safer approach would be to start a `Stopwatch` instance. That doesn't depend on the system time at all. So "current time" would be the value of the `Stopwatch` instance's `Elapsed` property.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep a sorted queue, but schedule a `System.Timers.Timer` to the time of the first event in the queue. When the event triggers I pick one element at a time from the queue, process the element, peak at the next to see if the time has passed. If the time has passed, process the event, otherwise schedule a timer for the remaining time.

When new event arrive you insert them in the sorted queue. If they happens to be first in the queue, reset the timer and restart it with the interval to the new first element.

This all assumes you need to trigger something to happen. If you just want to know when someone asks if there is a new event you don't need no timers, nor extra threads to handle the queue. Just check your event queue when someone asks.